# Meaning of this definition of a system of ODE:s? (Multivariable ODE?)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, definition

I always thought an ODE had *one* independent variable:

> For a system of $n$ ODE:s, we have a vector function $f$ of *one* variable $t$, $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R^n$ and 
>   \begin{align}
> \dot x(t)=f(t,x(t))
> \end{align}

However, in *Ordinary Differential Equations* by Logemann and Ryan, the defintion is

> Our goal is the study of systems of ordinary differential equations of the form
>   $$
> \dot x(t)=f(t,x(t))
> $$
>   Here $f:J\times G\rightarrow \mathbb R^N$ is a suitably regular function, $J\subset \mathbb R$ is an interval and $G$ is a non-empty open subset of $\mathbb R^N$.

**From "$J\times G$", $f$ is now a function of $N+1$ variables: $f:\mathbb R^{N+1} \rightarrow \mathbb R^N$**.

*But hey, it is an ODE, $f$ should be function of one variable?*

I'm stuck at this definition, I can't wrap my head around this!

I appreciate any clarification/reference. Thanks!

Comment: $f$ is a known function. "ODE" means that the unknown function $x$ has one argument. (Besides, even in your original example, $f$ is a function of two variables: $t$ and $x$.)

Comment: The function $t \mapsto f(t,x(t))$ *is* a function of one variable. But the function $(t,y) \mapsto f(t,y)$ is a function of two.

Comment: $J\times G$ is a [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product).

Answer (score 0):

An ODE can be a function of as many variables as you like, the point is that there are only *derivatives* in one variable - this variable is often denoted $t$ (for time).

E.g. $t\mapsto x(t),$ $[0,1]\to \mathbb R^3$ can be thought of as a particle satisfying some ODE $$\frac{d}{dt}x(t)=f(t,x(t)),\quad x_0=x.$$ This is an ODE, as only a time-derivative occurs -- despite the fact that $f:[0,1]\times\mathbb R^3\to \mathbb R^3$ is a function of several variables. Indeed, $f$ needs to be a function of many variables as the solution to the ODE lives in $\mathbb R^3$ and we are composing $f$ with this solution!

Comment: Thanks! When we write $f(t,x_t)$, do you mean $x_t$ is a function of $t$?. If so $f(t,x_t)$ is explicit $f(t,t_t(t))$, correct? But my problem here is that now $f$ must be a single variable function. I don't grasp how it could be a multivariable function.

Comment: Sorry I was using, $x_t =x(t)$  -- I have now changed the notation. I don't quite understand what you're saying: $x$ is a function $x:[0,1]\to\mathbb R^3$ and $f$ is a function $f:[0,1]\times\mathbb R^3\to \mathbb R^3$. So why do you think $f$ is a single-variable function?

Comment: Hmm, I will try to explain what I mean. If we forget ODEs for a moment. If I have a function $f(x,y)$, this is a function $f:\mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R$, right? Suppose I have a another function $g(x,y(x))$, this is just a function of one variable, right?

Comment: Read Chappers' comment above -- s/he's already answered that question. $g$ is a function of many variables. The composition $x\mapsto g\circ(x,y(x))$ is a function of one variable.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a function

$$F(u,v) = [u^2 v,  uv, 4v]$$

This is a vector-valued function of two variables: $F : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$.

Now, suppose you are interested in finding a function $y:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ such that:
\begin{align*}
\dot y(t) = [t^2 y(t),\, t\cdot y(t),\, 4y(t)]
\end{align*}

You could express this problem by saying that you are looking for a function of one variable $y:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ such that for all real $t$ in an area of interest, the following equation is true:

$$\dot y (t) = F(t, y(t))$$

Evidently, both $\dot y$ and the composite function $h(t)\equiv F(t, y(t))$ are functions of a single variable. This is what makes the equation an *ordinary differential equation*.

$F$ has two independent variables. But the problem you've set up— find a function $y:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $\dot y = F(t, y(t))$ has only single-valued functions on both sides.

---

Maybe another way to put this is in terms of composition: given a function $y:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, you can explicitly mention a function $G_{[y]}:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ where $G_{[y]}(t) \equiv \langle t,\, y(t)\rangle$.

Then $F(t, y(t))$ can more clearly be written as a composition $F\circ G_{[y]}$ which sends $$t\mapsto \langle t,\,y(t)\rangle \mapsto F(t, y(t)).$$

$F$ is a function with two free variables (named $u$ and $v$, above). In contrast, $F\circ G_{[y]}$ is a function with one free variable (named $t$).

With an ordinary differential equation, you are searching for a function $y$ such that for all real $t$ of interest,
$$\dot y = F \circ G_{[y]}$$

that is, such that $\dot y(t)$ and $F(t, y(t))$ are equal as functions of $t$.

---

I write the function as $G_{[y]}$ as a reminder that $G$ was defined in terms of a particular function $y:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. In particular, $G_{[y]}$ has a geometric interpretation: it is the graph of $y:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: In your first example, what is the dimension of the values of $y$? You mix 1 and 3 quite deliberately.